# Google Sheet Script to Duplicate Master Sheet & Rename

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to automate duplication of master sheet & at the same time rename the current master sheet to the current day.

Process:

1. Lets say the Master Sheet was named for yesterday's date "04/18/2022"
2. Duplicate the Master Sheet and rename it after duplication to the current date "04/19/2022"
3. Rename the duplicated sheet to remove "Copy of"

Greatly appreciate the help

Comment: What have you tried s far ? you can use `duplicateActiveSheet()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function duplicateTemplate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1)
  var d0 = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var d1 = Utilities.formatDate(today, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(d0).activate()
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet().setName(d1)
};
```

Take care of the time zone in the script editor. To change if needed, click the gear on the left side of the script editor, check the third box, go back to the script editor and select appsscript.json. Change as necessary.

edit : if "yesterday's sheet" does not exist, this script will try to find the most recent from last week

```
function duplicateTemplate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const today = new Date();
  const d1 = Utilities.formatDate(today, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  let previousDay = new Date();
  let n = 1
  while (n <= 7) {
    previousDay.setDate(today.getDate() - n++)
    let d0 = Utilities.formatDate(previousDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(d0)
    if (sh != null) {
      sh.activate()
      ss.duplicateActiveSheet().setName(d1)
      break
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. i edited it a little to suit my needs. I don't understand codes but somehow managed to do by editing yours.  I wonder if it's possible to duplicate the date when a weekend passed? As I only need weekdays, the yesterday code would not be valid as it would return with an error. ^_^

Comment: I have posted an edit to find the most recent sheet within past week

Comment: Thank you for this. I tweaked it a little. Thankfully I understood the script a little. I used the following       ss.getSheetByName(d0).setName(d1)
      ss.duplicateActiveSheet().setName(d0)
      ss.getSheetByName(d1).activate()
      sh.activate()
      ss.getRange('2:1906').activate();
      ss.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

Answer (score 0):

#### Make a duplicate every day from yesterdays master

```
function dupsht() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dt = new Date();//today
  const ydt = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate() - 1);//yesterday
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(ydt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy"));
  ss.insertSheet(Utilities.formatDate(dt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy"),{template:sh})
}
```